# Recognizing tables and iamge in PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, pdfbox, tabula

My goal is to count the number of tables and images in PDF files. I do NOT need to extract the content of tables or charts. I used Tabula and pdftotext and they both extract content but I didn't find a function to count the number of tables and charts. I believe Tabula must have such a function to identify a table before it starts to extract content in tables because it will skip content which is not in a table. (I used Word to create a PDF file to confirm that. The file is named check.pdf in the link below).

My current solution is: since there is "multiple_table" option in Tabula, I can count the number of elements in DataFrame with `len(DataFrame)`. However, I cannot test it due to some font issue. (See error message below)

`Oct 01, 2019 8:25:15 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider addTrueTypeFont
SEVERE: Could not load font file: C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\mstmc.ttf`

[Please refer to this LINK for a sample PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/21lu3y8ph3a58z2/AAC-J18zmQv2ZF6TWJy2hUfua?dl=0). For this sample file, my desired output will be 3 tables (1 on each page of 1, 4, and 5) and 1 chart (on Page 4). I use Python but I'm open to any other language. Any help is highly appreciated for either the font issue or table recognition.

Comment: That error message is not related to your problems. This is most probably happening during the building of the font cache, and the bad font is skipped.